# Powershell condition parametersetname validateset

Tags: function, powershell, validation, parameters

I know how to use ValidatetSet and ParameterSetName. I need to change dynamically the value of a ParameterSetName according to a previous value selected in ValidateSet. Is this possible?

it seems that Dynamic Parameters exist:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15994.powershell-advanced-function-parameter-attributes.aspx#Dynamic_Parameters

My use case:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [string]$Symbol,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [ValidateSet("BUY", "SELL")]
    [string]$Side,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
    [ValidateSet("Market", "Limit", "Take limit")]
    [string]$OrderType,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$Price,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$StopPrice,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$Quantity,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] 
    [string]$quoteOrderQty
)
```

many conditions needed, e.g if 'Market' is selected from `$OrderType` then `$quoteOrderQty` is required and then should be part of the same ParameterSetName.

Hope I'm clear enough, please advise if you have a better approach.
Thanks a lot

Yann

Comment: I am not aware that `ParameterSetName` has conditional options. If this is really necessary, maybe consider adding a 'Market' switch parameter which sets the `ParameterSet`.

Comment: This is what the google search leads to. With the "good" keywords and some sleep, I found what I posted in the next answer.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic parameters are parameters of a cmdlet, function, or script that are available only under certain conditions.
You can also create a parameter that appears only when another parameter is used in the function command or when another parameter has a certain value.

The DP1 parameter is available in the Get-Sample function only when the value of the Path parameter starts with HKLM:

```
function Get-Sample {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param([String]$Name, [String]$Path)

  DynamicParam
  {
    if ($Path.StartsWith("HKLM:"))
    {
      $attributes = New-Object -Type `
        System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
      $attributes.ParameterSetName = "PSet1"
      $attributes.Mandatory = $false
      $attributeCollection = New-Object `
        -Type System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]
      $attributeCollection.Add($attributes)

      $dynParam1 = New-Object -Type `
        System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter("DP1", [Int32],
          $attributeCollection)

      $paramDictionary = New-Object `
        -Type System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary
      $paramDictionary.Add("DP1", $dynParam1)
      return $paramDictionary
    }
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.1#dynamic-parameters